# Django list Category wont work

Tags: django, list

i want to list all of my categorys in a django template
but i only getting back nothing, any idea:

**category_list:html**

```
{% extends 'quickblog/base.html' %}
{% load readmore %}

{% block content %}
    {% for categories in categories %}
            <h1>{{ categories.titel }} {{ categories.post_set.count }}</h1>
            <p>{{ categories.description|readmore:15|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

"readmore" is only a templatefilter, please ignore it.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^categories/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='quickblog/category_list.html'), name='categories'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = EncryptedCharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Title")
    description = EncryptedTextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    categorycover = fields.ImageField(upload_to='categorycovers/', blank=True, null=True, dependencies=[
        FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
            format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 350, 'max_height': 350}))
    ])
    categoryicon = fields.ImageField(upload_to='categoryicons/', blank=True, null=True, dependencies=[
        FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
            format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 16, 'max_height': 16}))
    ])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the data for `categories` supposed to be coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use same variables names in for

```
{% for categories in categories %}
```

You should use

```
{% for category in categories %}
```

Where is your categories variable is? Template as View you load only the html, you dont have loaded categories variable to use, you can do 2 things...

**Custom Context Processors** - The varible you set using context processors will be avaible in all your templates, this is common used to check user stats without having to manualy do that in your views, **in your case use this only if you want to use categories variables in all your pages**

Declare your context function

```
def foobar_processor(request):
    return Category.objects.all()
```

Load it on your settings.py

```
'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'foo.bar.processors.foobar_processor',
                ...,
            ],
         }
```

source: https://www.webforefront.com/django/setupdjangocontextprocessors.html

**Views** - You can setup one view to your url in that view you can load your context and send it to your html page

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

from .models import Category

class HomePageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "quickblog/category_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

Source: http://pythonclub.com.br/class-based-views-django.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't reassign `categories` in the loop. Use a different variable name.

```
{% for categories in categories %}
```

Instead:

```
{% for category in categories %}
```

Also. Where do you define the `categories` template context variable? By default the generic `ListView` inserts a context variable named `object_list`. The `TemplateView` only adds context variables captured from the url pattern.

I suggest you create a view subclassing `ListView`

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from myapp.models import Category

class CategoryListView(ListView):

    model = Category
    template_name='quickblog/category_list.html'
```

template:

```
{% for category in object_list %}
```

Comment: i now created the following URL: `url(r'^categories/$', views.CategoryListView.as_view(), name='categories'),`

view:
`class CategoryListView(ListView):

    model = Category
    template_name='quickblog/category_list.html'`

And template is now: `{% for category in object_list %}` ...

but its still not working for me.

Comment: Make sure you are using `{{ category.title }}`, `{{ category.description }}` etc. inside the loop in the template. And of course, you must have some Category instances in the database.

Comment: That also works. But remember that naming counts. Using a plural name for what's actually single Category instance makes your code harder to understand and debug. I highly recommend using descriptive and consistent variable names.